Adding an IMAGE inside the ::before Selector
I wanted to add an Icon of Quotation Marks before the start of my paragraph, because I've seen this being done in some other websites.
So I tried to play a bit with the  width, height & font-size properties - But I can't figure out how to scale that image down to fit the size of the paragraph.
HERE IS THE QM ICON:

HERE IS THE CODE:


.article {
  padding-top: 2%;
}

.article::before {
  content: url(https://i.sstatic.net/mdeKRzYD.png);
  display: inline-block;
  /* top: 4px; */
  /* float: left; */
  /* width: 13px; */
  font-size: 10px;
}
<div class="article">
  <p>Blah blah blah, some text to fill the space.</p>
</div>




Frankly, I'd use a background-image rather than the actual image - https://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/vYwGrry

I think we aren't clear what 'to fit the size of the paragraph' means. The answers so far have the quote mark at the height of a line of text, but do you want the  quotation mark to be the height of the paragraph?

I want the quotation mark to be at the exact same height of the line of text (And stay only there - Especially after there will be other lines in the paragraph beneath it)

Woops, forgot the hashtag, sorry @AHaworth

No need to use an image, you can did it in css only:
blockquote {
    font-family: Georgia, serif;
    font-size: 18px;
    font-style: italic;
    width: 500px;
    margin: 0.25em 0;
    padding: 0.35em 40px;
    line-height: 1.45;
    position: relative;
    color: #383838;
}

blockquote:before {
    display: block;
    padding-left: 10px;
    content: "\201C";
    font-size: 80px;
    position: absolute;
    left: -20px;
    top: -20px;
    color: #7a7a7a;
}

blockquote cite {
    color: #999999;
    font-size: 14px;
    display: block;
    margin-top: 5px;
}

blockquote cite:before {
    content: "\2014 \2009";
}

Original answer: Make big quotes with <blockquote>
If you want to add your own icon or image:
blockquote {
    font-family: Georgia, serif;
    font-size: 18px;
    font-style: italic;
    width: 500px;
    margin: 0.25em 0;
    padding: 0.35em 40px;
    line-height: 1.45;
    position: relative;
    color: #383838;
}

blockquote:before {
    display: block;
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px; 
    content: "";
    background-image: url('https://img.freepik.com/vecteurs-libre/muffin-aux-bleuets-isole_1308-120886.jpg?size=626&ext=jpg&ga=GA1.1.229629212.1696869377&semt=sph'); 
    background-size: contain;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0px; 
    top: 10px;
}

blockquote cite {
    color: #999999;
    font-size: 14px;
    display: block;
    margin-top: 5px;
}

blockquote cite:before {
    content: "\2014 \2009";
}

And now you can play with the style however you want. I hope this answer helped you!

That looks exactly as the one I saw! But can I put in there somewhere an image of my own - INSTEAD of the default quotation marks of the CSS? Thank you!

Sorry for the late, hope my new edit help you

It was a pleasure

Hi again! If I want to have a small quote block - That has the quotation marks at the same position on both sides horizontally - How do I make the quotation marks appear both on the left and right of the 'blockquote::before'? Thank you!!

I made a codepen for you: https://codepen.io/Harvard-University/pen/wvbGRZz and hope this will help you ! I highly recommend you to learn more about position in css If you don't already know how it works

It was a pleasure

You can use background-image and background-size together with position absolute. You can also add transform: translate to better adjust its position


.article {
 margin-left:35px;
 position:relative;
}

.article::before {
  content: '';
  background-image: url('https://i.sstatic.net/mdeKRzYD.png');
  background-size: 20px 20px;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  position:absolute;
  left:0;
  top:0;
  width:30px;
  height:30px;
  transform:translate(-100%,-50%);
}
<div class="article">
  <p>Blah blah blah, some text to fill the space.
    Blah blah blah, some text to fill the space.Blah blah blah, some text to fill the space.Blah blah blah, some text to fill the space.Blah blah blah, some text to fill the space.
  
  </p>
</div>




Updated code with background-repeat :no-repeat
